# tomcat and java.security.Security

Tags: java, security, tomcat

I have tomcat 6.0 with 2 webapps. One of them executes the following code:

```
java.security.Security.addProvider(new cryptix.jce.provider.CryptixCrypto());
```

This makes this provider available in the second app but I don't want that.

Please explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Providers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Security.html#getProviders%28%29) are global.

> Returns an array containing all the installed providers. The order of the providers in the array is their preference order.

The only thing you might have control over is the preference order of the providers.  You can't make one set of providers available to one part of your code and not to another without running them in separate JVMs, since `java.security` is, I believe, loaded by the bootstrap classloader.