# NoClassDefFoundError on BouncyCastle class

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, noclassdeffounderror, bouncycastle

I have NoClassDefFoundError after some time on my WebApps with BC classes:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/util/Pack  
  at org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESFastEngine.unpackBlock(Unknown Source)
  at org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESFastEngine.processBlock(Unknown Source)
  at org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher.decryptBlock(Unknown Source)
  at org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher.processBlock(Unknown Source)
  at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.processBytes(Unknown Source)
  at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher$BufferedGenericBlockCipher.processBytes(Unknown Source)
  at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineUpdate(Unknown Source)
  at javax.crypto.Cipher.update(DashoA13*..)...
```

After a tomcat restart, the error disappears and reappears after 1 or 2 days.

The BC jar hasn't been tampered with.

BC is registered and used like this :

```
// registration
if (Security.getProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME) == null)
{
  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}

SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec("_mykey__mykey__mykey__mykey__myk".getBytes(), "AES");
IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("_iv__iv__iv__iv_".getBytes());
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

System.out.println(cipher.getProvider()); // prints "BC version 1.53"

// encryption
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv);
cipher.update("clearContent".getBytes());
byte[] cipheredContent = cipher.doFinal();

// decryption
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, iv);
cipher.update(cipheredContent);
byte[] clearContent = cipher.doFinal();

System.out.println(new String(clearContent)); // prints "clearContent"
```

Here are the components :

- java 6
- tomcat 6
- bcprov-jdk15on-153.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder
- jce6 unlimited strength

Am I missing something ?

Comment: looks like some horrible classloading issue. If your app has a starting point, I'd recommend you to add some code during the app startup to force the classloader to load BC classes

Comment: @Leo tried it with no success when doing it in `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)`

Comment: it seems to me problem with your jar file. Download this jar file again

Comment: @Ghayel if it was a problem with the jar, it would never work. It works perfectly after the server start and start throwing the error after some days.

Comment: I said it because if the jar was okay then it never through this error. may be some class or classes missing in this jar

Comment: @Ghayel the jar is signed and jarsigner tells me it hasn't been tampered with. I also looked at the class (Pack) and there is only static methods in it so it can't be an error in the static init of the class causing the exception.

Comment: Its not a good idea to put service providers like a JCE provider in an application classloader. Just install it in a shared or boot classloader of Tomcat. Otherwise changes are high that an other web app has registered the driver and yours wont find it. (having said that its not quite clear why the specific place would fail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @eckes, this pointed me in the right direction even if I don't encounter this problem since I dockerized everything some years ago.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/9911395